# Hide clicked button after toggle

Tags: javascript, toggle

I'm using this code to toggle the visibility of a section. When the button is clicked, the section shows.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("offerte-toggle");
  if (x.style.display === "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="myFunction()" id="knop-doorz" class="witte-randen">Offerte opvragen</a>
```

How can I hide the button after it has been clicked?

Comment: Your button id is `knop-doorz`, so `document.getElementById("knop-doorz");`. But how you will show it again? on which basis? It will not be shown again because you will not see it on screen to click it again

Comment: And element with id="offerte-toggle" is missing from the code.

Answer (score 0):

your JS code is targetting an element with id `offerte-toggle` but in your html, the  has an id of `knop-doorz`

Either edit the html id to match the JS or vice versa.

You also don't need to do the if check, just simply set `x.style.display = 'none';` before the closing `}` tag.